# Using python-crontab to create a reboot without a success

Tags: python, linux, cron

I used to manually create scheduled tasks on Linux by entering crontab -e in the terminal, editing the tasks, for example, `@reboot sleep 30 && /usr/bin/python3 /../to python file path/xx.py`, and then redirecting the output to a **crontab_log.txt** file.

Now, I want to create this post-reboot scheduled task using a Python script with the lib `python-crontab`. After executing the following code, it always prints the **task already exists**. However, when I use the command crontab -l, there are no scheduled tasks listed.

Any suggestions or advice regarding this issue.Thanks.

```
from crontab import CronTab
import os

def create_crontab_task():
    try:
        current_user = os.getlogin()
        print(f"current_user: {current_user}")

        command = '/usr/bin/python3 /python script file path.py >> crontab_log.txt 2>&1'
        cron = CronTab(user= current_user)
        existing_jobs = cron.find_command(command)
        
        if not existing_jobs:
            job = cron.new(command=command)
            job.setall('@reboot')
            cron.write()
        else:
            print('task already exists！！')
    except Exception as e:
        print('create crontab task：',e)

create_crontab_task()
```

Comment: `cron.find_command()` is an iterator. You can't use it as a boolean.